# unable loop particular column with multiple records from csv to mysql select statement

Tags: python, pandas, mysql-python

I am trying to read csv file which contain list of Id's and pickup those Id's one by one and search into select statement. Below code pickup only one Id and gives the result, loop stops there itself after first Id. It doesn't pickup all the Id's one by one and search those in select statement.

```
Test = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')

for record in Test:
    query = ("SELECT * FROM eprofile where Id in ('%s');"% record)
    ep1 = pd.read_sql_query(query, mydb)
    print(query)
    ep1.to_csv('EPROFILE-BKP-' + str(date.today()) + '.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: You only want to do one query.  So, clearly, doing one query per row, as you are doing, is wrong.  You need to build up a single query with all your IDs in it, and pass that large string to `read_sql_query`.  You should be able to create a list of IDs, pass that as the `params` parameter, and have the SQL be "SELECT * FROM eprofile WHERE id IN (%s);".

Comment: However, the exact syntax for substituting depends on which database backend you're using.  You'll have ti look it up.